# Has a new map of the Galaxy (far, far away) been released?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, map

There are many maps of the *Star Wars* Galaxy floating around. One thing I like about them is that they show the entire galaxy was not controlled by the Empire and that even a large portion of the galaxy was still uncharted.

In *The Force Awakens* we see two major factions (Resistance/New Republic and First Order). The New Republic was formed once the iron fist of the Empire was broken. The First Order is the reformation of the remnants of the Empire.

I was wondering if there was a new map released that shows what parts of the Galaxy each faction controls now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. The following map appears in the [Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary).

It doesn't, however contain the sort of granular political detail that would make it useful for your purposes

[image]

Comment: Pshhhhh.... I can actually count the  number of systems labeled on there.

Comment: @Skooba - Yeah, it's not exactly Star Wars: The Essential Atlas, is it?

Comment: Tatooine is right next to Geonosis?!

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Evidently.

Comment: Does any of this conflict with earlier, more detailed maps (eg general location of planets/systems)?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the route from Naboo to Coruscant from TPM made Tatooine a good stopping point for repairs.

Comment: Hyperspace corridors have no bearing to physical location maybe?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Hyperspace = Build like an inner city school, where you have to walk a mile to get to the other side of an alarmed door.

Comment: @iMerchant - You should ask that as a new question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Galactic rotation?

Comment: @ThePopMachine That was the case even before Disney: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/10/MainGalaxy.png/revision/latest?cb=20130325041255.

Comment: @Richard Maps of hyperspace corridors suggest there were shorter paths between Naboo and Corruscant: http://www.swgalaxymap.com/. At least they appear shorter; nothing says actual distance corresponds to hyperspace distance/time. It could also have more to do with being backwater enough that they could maintain secrecy without actually being impractically far away, but I think we're drifting into, "This should be a new question," territory.

Answer (score 13):

A map of the galaxy is shown in *The Force Awakens*.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if the First Order/New Republic divide is shown, though.

Comment: Ah, I have watched the movie a *few* times now and did not even realize it was the whole galaxy... i thought it was just a piece and BB-8 had a piece of the piece!

Comment: While this is in the movie, there doesn't seem to be any information you can actually glean from it other than perhaps that Luke is in the mid or outer rim.

Comment: @Skooba - While that's a good way to make sense of it IMHO, there's a pretty clear spiral in the middle of it, strongly implying this is showing the entirety of some kind of spiral supersystem. I'm not aware of anything smaller than a galaxy ever being shown to have a spiral organization. So that map would *have* to encompass an entire galaxy at a minimum.

Comment: I don't think the spoiler tags are needed. The whole question is about TFA.

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe its the spiral thing from TESB.