# Are there differences in the new Star Wars canonical map vs previous maps?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, map

Based on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/128398/54605) to a previous question, *The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary*, there is a new map. Are there any differences (e.g. planet/star system locations, etc) from other Star Wars maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to come up with the following animation. Although some of the planets in the new map are *missing* from the earlier map, none of the systems found on both maps are dramatically far away from where they should be, and all within a reasonable margin that could be excused by artistic differences and differences in scaling.

[image]

Comment: Yeah they did not ruin every thing!

Comment: (Just some things)

Answer (score 3):

The differences are fairly minor. While the EU/Legends map is much more detailed and has much more systems marked on it, the systems that appear on both maps are more or less exactly where they were before. Regions are virtually the same.

The differences I've noticed are:

- system placement and shape differences so minor they can easly be counted as art erorrs
- both maps have systems that don't appear on the other
- Unknown Regions look smaller on the new map, but they are not marked clearly, so it's hard to tell

**EU/Legends map**
[image: EU/Legends map]

**New canon map**
[image: New canon map]